# nested dictionary in list to dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, json-normalize

Have a json input from api:

```
{
  "api_info": {
    "status": "healthy"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "timestamp": "time", 
      "stock_data": [
        {
          "ticker": "string",
          "industry": "string",
          "Description": "string"
        }
      ]
     "ISIN":xxx,
     "update_datetime": "time"
    }
  ]
}
```

have initially run

```
apiRawData = requests.get(url).json()['items']
```

then ran the json_normalize method:

```
apiExtractedData = pd.json_normalize(apiRawData,'stock_data',errors='ignore')
```

Here is the initial output where the stock_data is still contained within a list.
stock_data  ISIN    update_datetime
0   [{'description': 'zzz', 'industry': 'C', 'ticker... xxx time

|  | stock_data | ISIN | update_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'description': 'zzz', 'industry': 'C', 'ticker...] | 123 | time |

What i would like to achieve is a dataframe showing the headers and the corresponding rows:

|  | description | industry | ticker | ISIN | update_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 'zzz' | 'C' | xxx | 123 | time |

Do direct me if there is already an existing question answered :) cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply convert your existing data frame into your expected one by using below code:

```
apiExtractedData['description'] = apiExtractedData['stock_data'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['description'])
apiExtractedData['industry'] = apiExtractedData['stock_data'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['industry'])
apiExtractedData['ticker'] = apiExtractedData['stock_data'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['ticker'])
```

And then just delete your stock_data column:

```
apiExtractedData = apiExtractedData.drop(['stock_data'], axis = 1)
```

Comment: @BrandonWong Hi, If you find the answer helpful then please accept it by clicking the button on left of answer :)

Comment: lol. @Divyessh,

Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.